How might one estimate the number of samples in a uniform distribution given only the sample range?
Let's say we have a fair roulette wheel with 2^256 segments, each printed with a unique integer in the range 0 to 2^256 - 1. Let's say that the wheel is hidden from us and that Trevor spins it N times. Trevor records the result each time. Finally, let's say that Trevor gives us the maximum, rmax, and minimum, rmin, result values that he observed.

How might we estimate N given only rmax and rmin, and assuming that Trevor and the wheel are trustworthy?

Playing around, with a trial and error approach, I see that
Estimated_N = 1 / (1 - ((rmax - rmin)/2**256))
has some promise, but I'm wondering what other methods/models there might be.

Could we quantify the confidence of the estimate?

By confidence, I mean how closely the estimate matches the actual N:
confidence = 1 - (abs(actual_N - estimated_N ) / actual_N)
Here a value of 1 is complete confidence.
I'm wondering if we can approximate, or say, anything about that value if actual N is unknown (only rmax and rmin are).

If so, does the confidence increase as the actual N increases?

If the actual N is constrained such that must be some power of 2, how might that improve confidence in the estimate?



See the German Tank problem.  Note that in the traditional statement, one knows the entire sample (not just max and min).  In your case, is $N$ shared or  are you just given the max and min and nothing else?

@lulu, interesting, thanks. The actual N is not shared; it's only the max and min we get in this problem.

On (2) and (3), it depends on what precisely you mean by confidence.  On (4), I would expect the answer to be no - there is nothing special about powers of $2$, either for the sample size or for the number of segments, though constraining the possible estimates in any way could have an effect. You could use a maximum likelihood approach or a method of moments approach, or something else.  A natural variant of this question would be to have a continuous uniform distribution on $[0,1]$, for example on a wheel of circumference $1$.

@Henry thanks, I've updated to try to improve the parts on confidence and will have a look that those approaches.

I will denote the endpoint of the range with $R$ (in the example this was $2^{256}$).
The Maximum Likelihood estimate for $N$ based on only $r_{\max}$ and $R$ is
$$\hat{N} = \frac{\ln\left(\frac{\ln\left(\frac{r_{\max}-1}{R}\right)}{\ln\left(\frac{r_{\max}}{R}\right)}\right)}{\ln\left(\frac{r_{\max}}{r_{\max}-1}\right)}$$
While the Maximum Likelihood estimate for $N$ based on only  $r_{\min}$ and $R$ is
$$\hat{N} = \frac{\ln\left(\frac{\ln\left(\frac{R-r_{\min}-1}{R}\right)}{\ln\left(\frac{R-r_{\min}}{R}\right)}\right)}{\ln\left(\frac{R-r_{\min}}{R-r_{\min}-1}\right)}$$

Proof:
Step I.
Given an iid sample $X_1,\dots,X_N \sim \text{UNIF}(\{0,\dots,R\})$, with $r_{\max} = \max_{i} X_i$ and $r_{\min} = \min_{i} X_i$, the distributions of $\mathbb{P}(r_{\max}=x_{\max}|N)$ and $\mathbb{P}(r_{\min}=x_{\min}|N)$ are the following:
$$\begin{align*}
&\mathbb{P}(r_{\max}=x_{\max}|N) = \mathbb{P}(r_{\max} \le x_{\max}|N) - \mathbb{P}(r_{\max} \le x_{\max}-1|N) = \\ &= \mathbb{P}(X_1 \le x_{\max}, \dots, X_N \le x_{\max}|N) - \mathbb{P}(X_1 \le x_{\max}-1, \dots, X_N \le x_{\max}-1|N) \stackrel{iid}{=} \\ &= \left(\frac{x_{\max}}{R}\right)^N - \left(\frac{x_{\max}-1}{R}\right)^N
\end{align*}$$
and
$$\begin{align*}
&\mathbb{P}(r_{\min}=x_{\min}|N) = \mathbb{P}(r_{\min} \ge x_{\min}|N) - \mathbb{P}(r_{\max} \ge x_{\min}+1|N) = \\ &= \mathbb{P}(X_1 \ge x_{\min}, \dots, X_N \ge x_{\min}|N) - \mathbb{P}(X_1 \ge x_{\min}+1, \dots, X_N \ge x_{\min}+1|N) \stackrel{iid}{=} \\ &= \left(\frac{R-x_{\min}}{R}\right)^N - \left(\frac{R-(x_{\min}+1)}{R}\right)^N
\end{align*}$$
Step II.
What is the $N$ that maximizes these probabilities? (Note: Since $r_{\max}=x_{\max}$ and $r_{\min}=x_{\min}$, I will use $r_{\max}$ and $r_{\min}$ in these functions instead.)
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial N} \mathbb{P}(r_{\max}=x_{\max}|N) = \left(\frac{r_{\max}}{R}\right)^N \ln\left(\frac{r_{\max}}{R}\right) - \left(\frac{Xr_{\max}-1}{R}\right)^N \ln\left(\frac{r_{\max}-1}{R}\right)$$
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial N} \mathbb{P}(r_{\min}=x_{\min}|N) = \left(\frac{R-r_{\min}}{R}\right)^N \ln\left(\frac{R-r_{\min}}{R}\right) - \left(\frac{R-r_{\min}-1}{R}\right)^N \ln\left(\frac{R-r_{\min}-1}{R}\right)$$
Solving for $\frac{\partial}{\partial N} \mathbb{P}(r_{\max}=x_{\max}|N)=0$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial N} \mathbb{P}(r_{\min}=x_{\min}|N)=0$:
$$\begin{align*}
\left(\frac{r_{\max}}{R}\right)^N \ln\left(\frac{r_{\max}}{R}\right) - \left(\frac{r_{\max}-1}{R}\right)^N \ln\left(\frac{r_{\max}-1}{R}\right) = 0 \\
\left(\frac{r_{\max}}{R}\right)^N \ln\left(\frac{r_{\max}}{R}\right) = \left(\frac{r_{\max}-1}{R}\right)^N \ln\left(\frac{r_{\max}-1}{R}\right) \\
\left(\frac{r_{\max}/R}{(r_{\max}-1)/R}\right)^N = \frac{\ln\left(\frac{r_{\max}-1}{R}\right)}{\ln\left(\frac{r_{\max}}{R}\right)} \\
\left(\frac{r_{\max}}{r_{\max}-1}\right)^N = \frac{\ln\left(\frac{r_{\max}-1}{R}\right)}{\ln\left(\frac{r_{\max}}{R}\right)} \\
\hat{N} = \frac{\ln\left(\frac{\ln\left(\frac{r_{\max}-1}{R}\right)}{\ln\left(\frac{r_{\max}}{R}\right)}\right)}{\ln\left(\frac{r_{\max}}{r_{\max}-1}\right)}
\end{align*}$$
Solving for the minimum goes the exact same way. $\square$

I have also tried to calculate an estimator which takes the joint distribution of $(r_{\max},r_{\min})$, but unfortunately I couldn't even come close to solving $\frac{\partial}{\partial N}\mathbb{P}(r_{\min}=x_{\min} \land r_{\max}=x_{\max})=0$. In any case, if $r_{\min}$ is significantly far away from $R-r_{\max}$, then we can assume that not enough samples have been taken from the initial distribution, and as such, $N$ is small.

Testing the method:
If $R=1000$, so the random variables come from the distribution $X_1,\dots, X_N \sim \text{UNIF}(\{0,\dots,1000\})$, and $r_{\max}$ is given, then using the first formula we can give an estimate for $N$:

if $r_{\max} = 900$, then $\hat{N} \approx 9.44$,
if $r_{\max} = 990$, then $\hat{N} \approx 94.81$,
if $r_{\max} = 999$, then $\hat{N} \approx 692.01$.

The formulas as symmetrical, so using $r_{\min}$, we'd get:

if $r_{\min} = 100$, then $\hat{N} \approx 9.44$,
if $r_{\min} = 10$, then $\hat{N} \approx 94.81$,
if $r_{\min} = 1$, then $\hat{N} \approx 692.01$.

These seem realistic to me.
